# arch linux systemd boot: missing /vmzlinuz-linux and /initramfs-linux.img

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel, boot-loader, systemd-boot

I am arch linux. One day it stopped showing in systemd boot menu. So I booted live arch via usb, mounted bootloader partition and ran `bootctl list --esp-path="/mnt"`. This is output:

```
  title: Arch linux(default)
     id: arch.conf
 source: /mnt/loader/entries/arch.conf
  linux: /vmzlinuz-linux (No such file or directory)
 initrd: /intel-ucode.img
         /initramfs-linux.img (No such file or directory)
options: root="LABEL=arch_os"
```

What should I do to fix this and boot normally ?
Thank you for your help

Comment: `systemd` is not a boot menu.  Do you mean the `grub` boot menu?  Are you dual-booting and able to get into another OS?

Comment: I meant menu of _systemd boot_. Yes I am booting one other system but that one works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Both `vmlinuz-linux` and `/initramfs-linux.img` are contained within the `linux` package.

to install this, using the live USB, execute the `arch-chroot /mnt` command to move into the root account. and then execute `pacman -Sy linux linux-firmware` to install the missing files. Then use the `exit` command to return to your live-usb where you can unmount and reboot into your system.

Note: make sure that the *boot* partition is mounted to `/mnt/boot` and ensure that you have a internet connection established before "chrooting" so you can download the packages.

More information on configuring your bootloader can be found in the Arch Wiki article on [systemd-boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-boot#Installing_the_EFI_boot_manager) and [the Installation Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide#Boot_loader).

Comment: Neither `/boot/vmlinuz-linux` or `/boot/initramfs-linux.img` are contained in the `linux` package. The former is set up post-install, and the latter is generated by `mkinitcpio`.

Comment: This partially worked. `linux` package is installed successfully. But `linux-firmware` package is throwing error while installing: _Failed to open file "/sys/devices/system/cpu/microcode/reload": Read-only file system_

Comment: From what I know, that error can be ignored. See https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=222373 for more on the error.

Comment: As Chris says, the initramfs is not included in the linux package. However it is generated when the package is installed, so re-installing the package is the correct process to follow or investigate.